# How do you send 2 emails to two different email addresses in Java?

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I have created a module for contact us. Here one user can send a mail about his concerns to admin and admin can send a reply mail to that particular user. So I have created 2 different mail templates, But I don't know how to send both at the same time.

Now I have completed sending reply email to  user, but I have not done sending mail to admin user.

My code for sending reply mail to user:

```
package com.spring.test.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class MailMail {

    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "mailSender")
    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {  
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }  

    public void sendMail(String to,  String subject, String msg) {  
        //creating message 

        System.out.println("mailsender == " + this.mailSender);

        try {
            String from = "emailFromAddress";

            JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage mimeMessage = sender.createMimeMessage();
            org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper helper = new org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false, "utf-8");
            mimeMessage.setContent(msg, "text/html");
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setFrom(from);
            helper.setTo(to);

            sender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
            sender.setUsername("emailServerUserName");
            sender.setPassword("emailServerPassword");
            sender.setPort(587);

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

            sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
            sender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to send mail to admin users also at a time?

Comment: Are you intending to make  your email process asynchronous and want to trigger both the email processing parallelly?

Comment: No, not asynchronous and want  two different templates to trigger both the email processing parallelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  implementation of sendMail should be completely driven from externalised parameters like email address to, email address from, subject , email template path and data with placeholder properties. Means none of the mentioned parameters be intialized, declared or manipulate in this method.

Probably with this your sendMail becomes a complete stateless service which you can call for sending various emails with different parameters

Comment: yes, my implementation of sendMail should be completely driven from externalized parameters but how can I send reply mail to user and at the same time another message template to admin user also? here two times calling this method.

Comment: I am assuming  for the 2 different events  you are mentioning there will be different entry points in your code

Comment: yes two different events there, So here sendMail method calling two times by two email templates but how to call one time this method?